# Automate Dplyr's mutate function

Tags: r, for-loop, dplyr, tidyverse, purrr

What is the best way to automate `mutate` function in one dplyr aggregation.

Best if I demonstrate on the example.
So in the first part of an example I am creating new columns based on values of variable `gear`. However, imagine I need to automate this step to automatically 'iterate' over all unique values of `gear` and creates new columns for each value.

Is there any how to do to so?

```
library(tidyverse)

cr <- 
  mtcars %>% 
  group_by(gear) %>% 
  nest()


# This is 'by-hand' approach of what I would like to do - How to automate it? E.g. we do not know all values of 'carb'

cr$data[[1]] %>% 
  mutate(VARIABLE1 = 
           case_when(carb == 1 ~ hp/mpg,
                          TRUE ~ 0)) %>%
  mutate(VARIABLE2 = 
          case_when(carb == 2 ~ hp/mpg,
                         TRUE ~ 0)) %>%
  mutate(VARIABLE4 =
          case_when(carb == 4 ~ hp/mpg,
                         TRUE ~ 0))

# This is a pseodu-idea of what I need to do. Is the any way how to change iteration number in ONE dplyr code?

vals <- cr$data[[1]] %>% pull(carb) %>% sort %>% unique()

for (i in vals) {
  message(i)

cr$data[[1]] %>% 
  mutate(paste('VARIABLE', i, sep = '') =  case_when(carb == i ~ hp/mpg, # At this line, all i shall be first element of vals
                          TRUE ~ 0)) %>% 
  mutate(paste('VARIABLE', i, sep = '') =  case_when(carb == i ~ hp/mpg, # At this line, all i shall be second element of vals
                          TRUE ~ 0)) %>% 
  mutate(paste('VARIABLE', i, sep = '') =  case_when(carb == i ~ hp/mpg, # At this line, all i shall be third element of vals
                                                            TRUE ~ 0))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to use `dummy_cols` from package `fastDummies`

Doing it for one dataframe at a time:

```
cr$data[[1]] %>%
  dummy_cols(select_columns = 'carb')%>%
  mutate_at(vars(starts_with('carb_')),funs(.*hp/mpg))
```

You can also do this first and the group by gear since you are not using gear value in calculation so it wouldn't matter. For that:

```
cr_new=mtcars %>%
  dummy_cols(select_columns = 'carb')%>%
  mutate_at(vars(starts_with('carb_')),funs(.*hp/mpg))%>%
  group_by(gear)%>%
  nest()
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, something like this would help -

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

bind_cols(mtcars, map_dfc(unique(mtcars$carb), 
 ~mtcars %>%
     transmute(!!paste0('carb', .x) := case_when(carb == 1 ~ hp/mpg,TRUE ~ 0))))
```

Answer (score -1):

It sounds a lot like what's called "the XY-problem".

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Please read about tidy data, and/or tidyr's pivot_longer/pivot_wider. Column names should not encode information.