# dplyr mutate new columns based on element we are iterating throught

Tags: r, for-loop, dplyr, aggregation-framework, purrr

What I am trying to do is to perform some aggregation based on unique elements of varaible we are iterationg.

I am able to perform what I need writing it manually. However, I would like to generalise this process so it can be performed automatically.

```
library(tidyverse)


df <- 
  tibble(
  LEVEL = c('1', '1.1', '1.2', '1.1.1'),
  A = c(1, 3, 20, 10),
  B = c(100, 20, 20, 20),
  DEPTH = c(1, 2, 2, 3)
)

df %>% 
  mutate(HEAD_VOLUME = 
                  case_when(DEPTH == 1 ~ A / B,
                            TRUE ~ 0)) %>% 
  mutate(HEAD_VOLUME = 
           case_when(DEPTH != 1 ~ nth(HEAD_VOLUME, 1),
                           TRUE ~ HEAD_VOLUME)) %>% 
  mutate(DEPTH_2_VOLUME = 
          case_when(DEPTH == 2 ~ A/ B, 
                          TRUE ~ 1)) %>% 
  mutate(DEPTH_3_VOLUME = 
           case_when(DEPTH == 3 ~ A/ B, 
                     TRUE ~ 1))
```

Now imagine that number of DEPTH will be larger and I need function to account for it.
I was thingking about a for loop and iterate over all unique value of DEPTH. However, we are not able (at least not in dplyr) to create new columns with `paste` function.

I was thinking about something like (pseudo-code):

```
df %>% 
  mutate(HEAD_VOLUME = 
           case_when(DEPTH == 1 ~ A / B,
                     TRUE ~ 0)) %>% 
  mutate(HEAD_VOLUME = 
           case_when(DEPTH != 1 ~ nth(HEAD_VOLUME, 1),
                     TRUE ~ HEAD_VOLUME)) %>% 
  mutate(paste('DEPTH_', i, 'VOLUME') =                # At this line i shall be second element of iter
           case_when(DEPTH == iter[i] ~ A/ B, 
                     TRUE ~ 1)) %>% 
  mutate(paste('DEPTH_', i, 'VOLUME') =                # At this line i shall be third element of iter
           case_when(DEPTH == iter[i] ~ A/ B, 
                     TRUE ~ 1))
```

Does anyone has any suggestion how to write generalisable script/function do be able to perform this aggregation to any dataframe with different values of LEVELS?

LEVEL 1 is main 'Above Hierarchie' (Tree root) - First Sub-subhierarchi (level 2). Last 'Sub-Sub hierarchi' is level 3. But in general we can have more than three levels - That is Why I want to automate this process.

Head Volume:
is calculated one - the reason it is created 2 times so that TREE_HEAD (Tree root) is calculated as 1/100 since all subsevels are comming from this root.

Comment: you can use `dummy_cols` from `fastDummies` package, as answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64463536/automate-dplyrs-mutate-function).

Comment: And can you please provide a bit deeper solution?.

Comment: Can you please explain your column 'HEAD_VOLUME'. You are creating it twice it seems.

Comment: Updated description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This gives the same output as your code and should also work in case DEPTH has more levels. Also it saves you from a `for` loop:

```
df %>%
  fastDummies::dummy_cols(select_columns = 'DEPTH') %>%
  mutate_at(vars(starts_with('DEPTH_')),funs(.*A/B)) %>%
  rename(HEAD_VOLUME=DEPTH_1) %>%
  mutate(HEAD_VOLUME=HEAD_VOLUME[1]) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(starts_with('DEPTH_')),~ifelse(.==0,1,.))
```

Below is the output (same as what comes from your code):

```
  LEVEL  A   B DEPTH HEAD_VOLUME DEPTH_2 DEPTH_3
1     1  1 100     1        0.01    1.00     1.0
2   1.1  3  20     2        0.01    0.15     1.0
3   1.2 20  20     2        0.01    1.00     1.0
4 1.1.1 10  20     3        0.01    1.00     0.5
```